# In R: Can I assign a data frame (say x) of row numbers =1 as the column header for another data frame (say y)?

Tags: r, dataframe, header

x is a data frame

```
print(x) 

rownames
1   Height
2   Weight
3   Age
4   Eye-color
```

I have another data frame `y` with 2 row of data to which I want to assign headers using data frame `x`.

```
print(y) 

John 180 150 35 Brown
Smith 153 250 23 Black
```

Some suggested this this:

```r
x <- x[is.na(x) == F]
```

(this converted the dataframe `x` into a character vector. **My 1st question is:** Is this necessary to add column header?)

```r
colnames(y) <- c(x)
```

**My 2nd question is** if I left `x` as data frame would I still be able to add them on as headers onto data frame `y`.

Is one way better than the other?

Comment: A reproducible example of what you are trying to do would be helpful. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `is.na(x) == FALSE` --> `! is.na(x)`, is there a reason that `== F` makes more sense to you? (Nothing serious, just curious.)

Comment: (1) `x[is.na(x) == F]` does not really make sense to me: `is.na(x)` on a frame will produce a matrix of logicals, and `x[is.na(x)==F]` will produce one long vector, of length `prod(dim(x))`. (2) If you're trying to subset `x` somehow on some quality of its columns, please be more clear with sample data and working code on that data.

Comment: If `x` already has 100 variables and `y` has 100 columns, why do you need more column headers for `y` (in `z`)?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your reply. I am a beginner in coding and so I am workin g upon someones existing code. I was curious why the recommended that I do x[is.na(x) == F] instead of ! is.na(x). Is there any reason why one would prefer over other?

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for your advice on framing my question better. As recommended here is an example data to reflect my problem more clearly (edited question above)

Comment: @RonakShah I think its being "approved".

Answer (score 0):

The column names of a data frame are a character vector.

When you set the column names of a data frame, you must set it to either (a) a character vector or (b) something that R can easily convert to a character vector with `as.character`.

You have a data frame `x` that includes values, `Height`, `Weight`, ..., and you want those values to be the column names of your data frame `y`. As `x` is a data frame, not a character vector, and `as.character(x)` doesn't work great, you will need to extract the values from `x` that you want to turn into a character vector.

There are many ways to do this. If the column names are in a column of `x` called `rownames` (this seems to be the case from your example), you could use these methods:

```
colnames(y) = x$rownames
colnames(y) = x[, "rownames"]
colnames(y) = x[["rownames"]]
```

If the column names are in the *first* column of `x`, you could use these methods:

```
colnames(y) = x[, 1]
colnames(y) = x[[1]]
```

If the column names are in the *only* column of `x`, you could use this method:

```
colnames(y) = unlist(x)
```

There are slight differences between all of these methods, but which one is "best" depends on context. Generally, it is better to use column names than column numbers, as those *tend* to be more invariant, and help you catch bugs if the data changes. It also makes for clearer code. The methods with `[` and `[[` allow you to use variables, e.g., you can do this:

```
column_with_names = "rownames"
colnames(y) = x[, column_with_names]
```

But this would not work with `$`.

In all of the cases, you can combine the extraction of the data from `x` with the assignment of column names to `y`, or you could do it separately:

```
# all at once
colnames(y) = x$rownames

# separately
y_colnames = x$rownames
colnames(y) = y_colnames
```

Which one is best depends on (a) Do you need to use the original `x` later for something else? (b) Will you need to use the extracted column names again later? (c) Is the extraction code so long that it makes sense to put it on a separate line for readability?

---

> Some suggested this:
>
> `x <- x[is.na(x) == F]`

This line of code removes missing values from `x`. Using `== F` is a bad habit, it would be better written `x[!is.na(x)]`. Since the `x` you show does not have missing values, it doesn't seem relevant to your question.